# Mixpanel Breaks Cucumber Javascript Tests

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber, capybara, mixpanel

I've implemented Mixpanel testing in a Ruby on Rails application - at most about 4 or 5 Mixpanel calls per page-load. These calls seem to break any Cucumber scenario for which I use the Selenium web-driver (with chromedriver).

I've found a solution in not loading the Mixpanel Javascript library in testing environment, but this seems like a large discrepancy to maintain between testing and production environments.

Why might these Mixpanel calls be causing tests to fail (it's only tests that use Javascript w/ selenium web-driver - non-js [webrat] tests succeed), and what might a better solution be than just not loading the Mixpanel js library?

Comment: Running into the same issue at our company. I think we're going to settle for the approach of disabling in test mode, and maybe setting up a stub object in its place.